# I keep receiving this uncaught error whenever i run php testRabbitMQClient.php

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I keep receiving this error everytime I run php `testRabbitMQClient.php`

```
testRMQClientPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getCredentials() in /home/andrew/git/rabbitmqphp_example/testRabbitMQClient.php:20
Stack trace:
\#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/andrew/git/rabbitmqphp_example/testRabbitMQClient.php on line 20
```

```
$type = getCredentials($username,$password);
```

Comment: read the error it say `Call to undefined function getCredentials()`  so  it means it doesn't defination of  `getCredentials($username,$password);` function in your code

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling here `testRabbitMQClient.php on line 20` does not exist.
As far as I can see this function `getCredentials` is a custom function and not part of the library you are using. If you try to connect directly it will work